ASP.Net Core Redirecting from POST endpoint to Custom URL
I am using a payment service. This service want me to send a callBackUrl while starting payment process. And the service sends a post request to my callBackUrl after 3D security page. And I am checking some datas and return status. But, I need to redirect user directly to a custom url after my checkings. In short, how can I redirect to custom url inside a post method?

Usually payment providers will offer the possibility of adding success/failure redirect urls when performing the call. Since it's the payment service making the call to your post method, I don't see how you could redirect the user (it's not their request being made). So, instead, you would use the success/failure url returned by the payment provider. In any case, if you let us know what provide you're using, it would be easier to help.

@akseli there is only one redirectUrl. The service send some datas inside body. And the frontend team say that we cannot create an endpoint allow POST requests. So we need to do that in backend side. But I need to redirect FE url at the end of my POST method. My payment service is private for our customer. They say that we cannot change the structure.

I solved my problem by sending response with 302 status code. You can see code below.
[HttpPost]
[Route("Callback")]
[AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<IActionResult> CallBackAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    ...
    var response = new ObjectResult(null)
    {
        StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status302Found
    };

    Response.Headers["Location"] = "https://google.com";
    return response;
}


The answer would be specific to the payment gateway you are using. As @akseli has mentioned in comment, Payment Gateways has success and Cancel URL parameters.
Following code is implementation of Stripe for processing payment and you can define options while creating session.
//var domain = "https://localhost:7050/";
var domain = Request.Scheme + "://" + Request.Host.Value + "/";

var options = new Stripe.Checkout.SessionCreateOptions
{

    SuccessUrl = domain+$"Customer/Cart/OrderConfirmation?id={ShoppingCartVM.OrderHeader.Id}",
    CancelUrl = domain+"Customer/Cart/Index",
    LineItems = new List<Stripe.Checkout.SessionLineItemOptions>(),                   
    Mode = "payment",
};

Let us know if this works.

For more reference, you can check the entire controller here. GitHub Repo

Thanks for answer. There is only one redirectUrl in the service we use. The service send some datas inside body after 3dsec screen. And the frontend team say that we cannot create an endpoint allow POST requests. So we need to do that in backend side. But I need to redirect FE url at the end of my POST method. My payment service is private for our customer. They say that we cannot change the structure.
